I teach Drama to 24 8th graders. I want to give them all the same film clip with no sound and them add the sound to it. How do I make this work?
This is part of a unit on technical theatre and sound design. Every student in the class has their own school-issued laptop. This class ends on December 21. This particular project needs to be accomplished without having to purchase any subscriptions or services to access sounds .

Having every student doing this from scratch on their own is too ambitious for a junior high school level project.  You could have a group of students work on incidental sfx, another on music, another on ambient sound, another on dialogue, etc, and then once you have all the elements assembled, each student could do their own mix.  But even that is a lot of work to complete in a month.

As a teacher myself, I don’t have any answers for you, but I do have admonition: prerequisites for teaching a unit are knowing how to do what you’re going to teach and being fully prepared to teach it. This is something I would have sorted out over the summer. Perhaps you inherited a curriculum and didn’t have time to plan and if so i think you’ll serve the students best by developing an alternate project that you can fully teach without last minute frantic preparation.

Well, you have a bit of work ahead of you and the students. Very ambitious (too?) if you ask me. Some things:

find a short film (be careful with copyrights).
distribute the film to the students, maybe as a compressed mp4.
select a preferred audio (or video editor) software. Preferrably one where you can see the video while editing sound 1)
write instructions on how to import the video into the software and how to export the resulting film with added sound.
find a preferred set of available sound effects. 2)
write instructions how to grab sound effects and how to import into the audio "pool".
write instructions on how to add the sound effects into the preferred editor.
do the full process yourself a few times to get experience to be able to help the students.


The editor could be either a full video editor or an audio editor that can import and sync videos. A full free fledged video editor (with steep learning curve) is Davinci Resolve. As for free audio you have to ask someone else.

BBC sound effects may be a suggestion.


